# How to display textbox data in wpf datagrid using MVVM model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Hi everyone my question is that i am working on wpf c# application which is based on MVVM pattern.The problem where i stuck is that i want my textboxes data to display in my datagrid by clicking a button but i am unable to did that and finally asking for some good suggestions and solutions.

My code in XAML:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>  
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="VLAN NAME"
        Foreground="Black"
        Opacity="0.8"
      />

    <TextBox 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="0,5,0,0"
        Height="25"
        Foreground="Black"
        Opacity="0.8"
        Width="Auto"
        Text="{Binding VlanName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
        />
    <Label 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="VLAN ID"
        Foreground="Black"
        Opacity="0.8"
        />
    <TextBox 
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="0,5,0,0"
        Height="25"
        Foreground="Black"
        Opacity="0.8"
        Width="70"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Text="{Binding VlanID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
        />

    <Label 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="IP FOR VLAN"
        Foreground="Black"
        Opacity="0.8"
      />

    <Grid 
      Grid.Column="1"
      Grid.Row="2">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>

      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox  
       Grid.Row="2"
       Grid.Column="0"
        Margin="5"  
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        MaxLength="3" 
        Width="30" 
        Foreground="Black"
        Opacity="0.8"
        Text="{Binding VlanIP1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"       
        />
      <TextBox  
       Grid.Row="2"
       Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="5"  
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        MaxLength="3" 
        Width="30" 
        Foreground="Black"
        Opacity="0.8"
        Text="{Binding VlanIP2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

        />
      <TextBox  
       Grid.Row="2"
       Grid.Column="2"
        Margin="5"  
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        MaxLength="3" 
        Width="30" 
        Foreground="Black"
        Opacity="0.8"
        Text="{Binding VlanIP3, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

        />
      <TextBox  
       Grid.Row="2"
       Grid.Column="3"
        Margin="5"  
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        MaxLength="3" 
        Width="30" 
        Foreground="Black"
        Opacity="0.8"
        Text="{Binding VlanIP4, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

        />
    </Grid>
    <Label 
        Grid.Row="3" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="VLAN PORT"
        Foreground="Black"
        Opacity="0.8"
      />
    <ComboBox
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableVlanPorts}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVlanPort}"
            >

    </ComboBox>

    <Button Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Content="Add VLAN"
            Margin="10,5,0,0"
            Style="{StaticResource AppButtons}"
            Command="{Binding AddVlan}" 
            Click="Add_Vlan"
            />      

    <Button Grid.Column="3" 
            Grid.Row="2"
            Content="Remove VLAN"
            Margin="10,5,0,0"
            Style="{StaticResource AppButtons}"
            Width="100"
            Command="{Binding RemoveVlan}"
            />

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="4"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
              Height="200"
              Margin="10,10,0,0"
              Name="dg"
              ItemsSource="{Binding vlan}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              > 

      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="S.No"    Binding="{Binding Path=S_No}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VLAN Name" Binding="{Binding Path=vname}"   />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VLAN ID"      Binding="{Binding Path=vid}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="           IP" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VLAN Ports" Width="100"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
```

C# code is:

```
public string VlanName
    {
      get
      {
        return this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName;
      }
      set
      {
        if (String.Equals(this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName, value))
        {
          return;
        }
        this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("VlanName");
      }
    }
  public string VlanID
    {
      get
      {
        return this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName;
      }
      set
      {
        if (String.Equals(this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName, value))
        {
          return;
        }
        this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("VlanID");
      }
    }
  public ICommand AddVlan
    {
      get
      {
        if (_addVlan == null)
          _addVlan = new RelayCommand(() => this.AddVlans());

        return _addVlan;
      }

    }
  void AddVlans()
    {
      Console.Write("Add vlan");
      var serial = new VLANSPropertyClass();
      serial.S_No = vlan.Count + 1;
      serial.vname = VlanName;
      serial.vid = VlanID;
      vlan.Add(serial);
    }
```

Firstly i  am displaying only two columns for testing.
Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: could you add the code for the property 'vlan'?

Comment: yes i did..{
  public class VLANSPropertyClass
  {
    public string vname { get; set; }
   
    public int S_No { get; set; }

    public string vid { get; set; }

    public string ip { get; set; }
  }
}

Comment: i mean the property that your datagrid is binding to: ItemsSource="{Binding vlan}" I'm expecting this to be some sort of collection of your VLANSPropertyClass

Comment: yes i did that in XAML:  ItemsSource="{Binding vlan}"

Comment: is there any need of setting DataContext??

Comment: you said this was mvvm, so i am right in assuming you have a viewmodel somewhere? and the viewmodel should have a property called 'vlan' which i would also expect to be a collection of your 'VLANSPropertyClass' if you don't have a property called 'vlan' then your datagrid wont have anything to bind to. And yes you do need to set a datacontext

Comment: yes i used collection and set in my ViewModel...  
public ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan { get; set; } 
but how to set datacontext?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52390/discussion-between-saad-ahmed-and-emybob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want, the `DataGrid` should be bound to the collection (e.g. ObservableCollection) where you store all the items, when you click the "Add" button, you call `Entities.Add(NewEntity);`, where `Entities` is the collection and `NewEntity` is a property of the view model. You bind the text boxes to the properties of `NewEntity`. i've made a small gist [here](https://gist.github.com/kurushimiamai/5a1d8b5717ce6e7b3cbe) to demonstrate.

Comment: i've used GalaSoft's ["MVVM Light Toolkit"](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), for the ICommand and INotifyPropertyChanged (i.e. `ViewModelBase`) implementations, but you can use whatever you like, of course.